# Why Graphql Result gives more json details than query requested

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, graphql, entity-framework-core

My Development Environment

- visual studio 2019
- dotnetcore 3.1  API
- GraphIQL 2.0.0
- GraphQL 2.4.0

I tested GraphQL. below image shows the error I got.

[image]

My StartUp.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;        
    }

 

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<miracleContext>(opt => opt.UseMySql(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:MiracleMariaDB"]));
        services.AddScoped<IDependencyResolver>(_ => new FuncDependencyResolver(_.GetRequiredService));
        services.AddScoped<IDocumentExecuter, DocumentExecuter>();
        services.AddScoped<IDocumentWriter, DocumentWriter>();
        services.AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<CompanyService>();
        services.AddScoped<CompanyRepository>();
        

        services.AddScoped<CompanyQuery>();
        services.AddScoped<CompanyType>();
        
        services.AddScoped<ISchema, MiracleSchema>();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        //services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => options.AllowSynchronousIO = true);
        //services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => options.AllowSynchronousIO = true);
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseGraphiQl("/graphql");
        

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

GraphQLController.cs

```
[Route("[Controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class GraphQLController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISchema _schema;
    private readonly IDocumentExecuter _documentExecuter;

    public GraphQLController(ISchema _schema, IDocumentExecuter _documentExecuter)
    {
        this._schema = _schema;
        this._documentExecuter = _documentExecuter;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] GraphQLQuery query)
    {
        if(query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(query));
        }

        var inputs = query.Variables?.ToInputs();

        var executionOptions = new ExecutionOptions
        {
            Schema = _schema,
            Query = query.Query,
            OperationName = query.OperationName,
            Inputs = inputs
        };

       var result = await _documentExecuter.ExecuteAsync(executionOptions).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
      
        if (result.Errors?.Count>0)
        {
            return BadRequest(result);
        }
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

CompanyType.cs

```
   public class CompanyType : ObjectGraphType<Company>
    { 
      public CompanyType()
      {
          Field(X => X.address_1);
          Field(X => X.address_2);
          Field(X => X.banner);
          Field(X => X.business_type);
          Field(X => X.city);
          Field(X => X.company_name);
          Field(X => X.contact_designation);
          Field(X => X.contact_person);
          Field(X => X.country_code);
          Field(X => X.created_by);
          Field(X => X.created_date, nullable: true);
          Field(X => X.email);
          Field(X => X.Id);
          Field(X => X.landline);
          Field(X => X.logo);
          Field(X => X.mobile);
          Field(X => X.registered_date);
          Field(X => X.status);
          Field(X => X.updated_by, nullable: true);
          Field(X => X.updated_date, nullable: true);
          Field(X => X.web);
      }
}
```

CompanyQuery.cs

```
public class CompanyQuery:ObjectGraphType
{
    public CompanyQuery(CompanyService companyService)
    {
        Field<ListGraphType<CompanyType>>(
           name :  "companies",
             resolve: context => {
                 return companyService.GetAll();
                 } );
    }
}
```

MiracleSchema.cs

```
public class MiracleSchema : GraphQL.Types.Schema
{
    public MiracleSchema(IDependencyResolver resolver) : base(resolver)
    {
        Query = resolver.Resolve<CompanyQuery>();
        //Mutation = resolver.Resolve<CompanyMutation>();
    }
}
```

CompanyRepository.cs

```
 public class CompanyRepository: ICompanyRepository
   {
      private readonly miracleContext _dbContext;

      public CompanyRepository(miracleContext dbContext)
      {
          _dbContext = dbContext;
      }

      public IEnumerable<Company> GetAll()
      {
          return _dbContext.Companies;
      }     
  }
```

CompanyService.cs

```
   public class CompanyService
    {
       private readonly CompanyRepository _companyRepository;

       public CompanyService(CompanyRepository companyRepository)
       {
           _companyRepository = companyRepository;
       }

       public IEnumerable<Company> GetAll()
       {
           return _companyRepository.GetAll();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As to the "Why doesn't it show the schema?" question, possibly it's because your MiracleSchema class has the wrong definition.

If you take a look at the [GraphQL Examples project](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples) its [StarWarsSchema class](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples/blob/master/src/StarWars/StarWarsSchema.cs) defines and expects an IServiceProvider instance via its constructor:

```cs
using GraphQL.Types;
using GraphQL.Utilities;
using System;

namespace StarWars
{
    public class StarWarsSchema : Schema
    {
        public StarWarsSchema(IServiceProvider provider)
            : base(provider)
        {
            Query = provider.GetRequiredService<StarWarsQuery>();
            Mutation = provider.GetRequiredService<StarWarsMutation>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still, I am getting the same issue..can anyone share with me a good working project sample which is developed with Dotnet core 3.1 API+ GraphQl,, I am struggling with this matter around more than one week..Thanks All